# calling express api using cron-tab vs using node-cron

Tags: node.js, cron

I need to do some queries, do some logic, generate result and populate a table with that result every day.
I have two options here.
I can create a express app which will be running at a port on localhost. I will do curl using linux `crontab`
Second option is to use `node-cron` or any other similar package.
Here I am confused which method to go with, because I don't know the pros and cons here.
Can someone suggest?

Comment: This is opinion based, so here is MO ... If I was you I wound go with node-cron, since it would be more friendly to node users, AND, it can be pushed to the repository

Comment: I've already been bitten by crontab. There is user crontab, system crontab, it does not share the same shell environment that interactive sessions. if you're on node, use node